# Why do I get one extra row when reading cursor object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

Why do I get 4 rows in 3 rows table when I run SELECT statement and UPDATE afterwards?

Below is an initial table, I'm using SQLite 3 v3.11.0:

```
animal  isMammal
------- ------- 
cat     1
dog     1
salmon  0
```

When I comment a 2nd line in `test()` function I get:

```
(u'cat', 1)
(u'dog', 1)
```

which is totally fine (I'm looking up mammals only), but when I make *salmon* a mammal before printing the cursor then I get:

```
(u'cat', 1)
(u'cat', 1)
(u'dog', 1)
(u'salmon', 1)
```

which for me is just weird...

---

```
import sqlite3


class DB:
    conn = None

    def connect(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('./database.db')

    def query(self, sql):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
        except (AttributeError, sqlite3.OperationalError) as e:
            self.connect()
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
        return cursor

    def query_many(self, sql, data):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
        except (AttributeError, sqlite3.OperationalError) as e:
            self.connect()
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
        return cursor

    def commit(self):
        self.conn.commit()


def populate_table(db):
    data = [('cat', 1), ('dog', 1), ('salmon', 0)]
    sql = 'INSERT INTO animals VALUES (?,?)'
    db.query_many(sql, data)
    db.commit()


def create_table(db):    
    # Drop table if exist
    sql = '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS animals'''
    db.query(sql)
    db.commit()

    # Create animals table
    sql = '''
        CREATE TABLE animals(
            animal text unique PRIMARY KEY, 
            isMammal boolean default 0
        )'''
    db.query(sql)
    db.commit()


def test(db):
    cur = db.query('SELECT * FROM animals WHERE isMammal=1') 
    db.query('UPDATE animals SET isMammal=1 WHERE isMammal=0') # w/o this line I got 2 rows
    db.commit()

    # I expect here to print mammals only
    for row in cur:
        print row

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = DB()
    create_table(db)
    populate_table(db)
    test(db)
```

Comment: If you start a SELECT and then modify the table partway through, it's undefined what parts of those modifications are seen by the SELECT. You can see both versions of an UPDATEd row. You can see the same unrelated row twice if things get moved, or you might not see it at all.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, it'd be reasonable if I got both versions of "salmon row" but I get "cat row"  doubled which I don't change. Now I see that if I copy the cursor results i.e. `result = list(cur)` just before UPDATE then my code works as expected (it prints two rows with mammals only). I'm just curious what happens inside when I don't copy the cursor in between?